how to programatically click dropdown menu item in a ag-grid cell
nextjs 14 and ag-grid-enterprise/ag-grid-react 32.1.0
One of the column uses a custom renderer to display a dropdown menu with two items. The custom cell renderer is a function component. One of the menu item is to open a popup window to display the details of the row. This is all good.
Now I have a requirement to open the popup window to display the details of a row in an event handler. I thought the first step is to get the custom cell renderer instance, but the getCellRendererInstances() method of grid-api allways returns an empty array, so I cannot actually get the cell renderer instance.
Does getCellRendererInstances() of the grid-api only work for class component?


Does getCellRendererInstances() of the grid-api only work for class component?

No, it works with functional components as well.
You did not share your code so I will make assumptions here to forward you to the right solution.
First of all, please use useImperativeHandle hook to expose your method to the grid.
Let's assume that this your custom cell renderer component
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react"

import type { CustomCellRendererProps } from "ag-grid-react"

export default forwardRef((props: CustomCellRendererProps, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            yourCustomFunction() {
                //
            },
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
})

Now we can access our cell renderer instances and run our custom function like that
const params = { columns: ["yourColumnName"] }
const instances = gridRef.current!.api.getCellRendererInstances(
params,
) as any[]

instances.forEach((instance) => {
    instance.yourCustomFunction()
})


Note that the getCellRendererInstances() method will return nothing if
the grid is scrolled far past the first row showing row virtualisation
in action.

Read more on https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/
